# C# Efficient way to check datagridview checkbox column for checked values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview and a checkbox column attached to it. If the user checks a few rows and then presses a button, I would like to be able to get a certain cell value from each row where the box was ticked.

Something maybe like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn1.Name].Value) == true)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the datagridview might contain up to 3000 or 4000 rows. I would like to see if there is a faster way to get the checked rows, other than to iterate through all the rows for the grid.

Comment: Why are you making your users sift through 4,000 rows?

Comment: 3000 or 4000 rows is not much.  Do you have an actual performance problem?

Comment: @LarsTech It is the user's wish. And they will also be able to filter through that.

Comment: @Paparazzi I'm still in the design stage of this, I don't think it would create a bottleneck, but if there's a better way in terms of performance I would prefer it.

Comment: You should avoid premature optimization.     If you are worried about performance then DataGridView and WinForms would certainly not be my pick.   You have picked a very heavy weight control and you are worried about the time to iterate row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to iterate all rows, then use temporary list of checked rows.
Then after button was clicked use values from that List

```
HashSet<DataGridViewRow> _CheckedRows = new HashSet<DataGridViewRow>();

private void DataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals(CheckBoxColumn1.Name) == false)
        return;

    DataGridViewRow row = DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn1.Name].Value) == true)
    {
        _CheckedRows.Add(row);
    }
    else
    {
        _CheckedRows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! I was late for a second with a similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could manage your own list of checked rows.
You would bind to the dataGridView1.CellClick event, and add/remove rows from the list:

```
var checkedRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

dataGridView1.CellClick += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.RowIndex != YOUR_CHECKBOX_COLUMN_INDEX)
    {
        return;
    }

    var cell = dataGridView1[args.ColumnIndex, args.RowIndex];

    if (cell.Value == null)
    {
        cell.Value = false;
    }

    cell.Value = !(bool)cell.Value;

    if ((bool)cell.Value)
    {
        checkedRows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[args.RowIndex]);
    }
    else
    {
        checkedRows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[args.RowIndex]);
    }
};
```

All you have to do then is:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in checkedRows)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq` like this :

```
var checkedRows = from DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows
                  where Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells[CheckBoxColumn1.Name].Value) == true
                  select r;

foreach (var row in checkedRows)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Cleaner syntax but I doubt it is faster

Answer (score 0):

Using `CheckBoxColumn1.Name` instead of `CheckBoxColumn1.Index` seems like a tiny bottleneck to me.

To avoid the casting to DataGridViewRow and Boolean, my suggestion is something like (not tested):

```
int colIndex = CheckBoxColumn1.Index; // or dataGridView1.Columns.IndexOf(CheckBoxColumn1.Name) ?
for ( int r = 0; r < dataGridView1.RowCount; r++ )
{
    if ( true.Equals( dataGridView1[colIndex, r].Value ) )
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The other answers that use cell events are better because the list of checked rows will be ready when needed, but also can be a bit harder to maintain/debug depending on how you do the filtering and rest. Here is my version:

```
private HashSet<int> checkedRowIndexes = new HashSet<int>();

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.ColumnIndex == CheckBoxColumn1.Index ) 
    {
        if ( true.Equals( dataGridView1[CheckBoxColumn1.Index, e.RowIndex].Value ) )
            checkedRowIndexes.Add(e.RowIndex);
        else 
            checkedRowIndexes.Remove(e.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fabio compiles for me https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0syx5449. The alternatives if needed are `cell.Value.Equals(true)` or `object.Equals( cell.Value, true )`